# Can't call variable from another object

Tags: javascript, methods

I have 2 objects: `myObject1` and `myObject2`.
I am trying to call a private variable from `myObject1` using `my0bject2` method called `increment`, but `console.log` says `NaN`.
Is there any way to call `myObject1` variable directly from `myObject2` method? Maybe extend it somehow?

```
var myObject1 = function() {

  var x = 0;

  return{}
}();

var myObject2 = function() {

  return{
    increment: function() {
        myObject1.x +=1;
        console.log(myObject1.x);
    }
  }
}();

myObject2.increment();
```

Comment: `return { x: 0 };` from the object 1

Comment: Just replace  var with this  ->  `this.x = 0`

Comment: @zerkms add that as the answer please before I do :P

Comment: @CarlMarkham it changes the code semantics, it's not obvious whether OP wants that or not. Otherwise go or it and get my +1 if you explain it ;-)

Comment: OP wants to reference `x` on `myObject1`. You could either use your answer, or specify `this.x` and return `this` rather than an empty object

Comment: @zerkms I agree that it's not really clear what OP wants. If `x` is to be a _private_ variable, then I wouldn't expect anything outside to be able to reach it. If it is to be _shared_ then that solves the problem, but is in conflict with the privacy thing.

Comment: @CarlMarkham see what vlaz said, those are exactly my thoughts.

Comment: @zerkms @vlaz I concur, my instinct tells me they want `x` and aren't bothered about private scope. Only time will tell

Comment: @zerkms I gave in to temptation, forgive me.

Comment: Yes, i'm not bothered by the private variable. I got many good answers. Thank you all.

Comment: remember to mark the one that helped you as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify `var x` within `myObject1` you are declaring that variable as private. The only thing that has access to that variable are methods within `myObject1`. As you noted, this variable is private.

You didn't make it clear if you wanted to keep it private or not so I will assume you just want to access it. You could do a couple of things here.
You could attach the variable as an object property of `myObject1` via `this`. `this` refers to the current scope (`myObject1`) so by saying `this.x` within `myObject1` you are saying `myObject1.x`. From that function, you will need to return `this` so that instances of it can access all of its public properties.

```js
var myObject1 = function() {
  this.x = 0;
  return this;
}();

var myObject2 = function() {
  return {
    increment: function() {
      myObject1.x +=1;
      console.log(myObject1.x);
    }
  }
}();

myObject2.increment();
```

You could also just return the properties that you want, in this case `x`. You have more control over what is returned in this case and you get the same result as above.

```js
var myObject1 = function() {
  var x = 0;
  return {
    x: x,  
  };
}();

var myObject2 = function() {
  return {
    increment: function() {
      myObject1.x +=1;
      console.log(myObject1.x);
    }
  }
}();

myObject2.increment();
```

Either way, these methods both expose the `x` property of `myObject1` making it public.

Comment: Similar to Aer0's answer, you are returning this, which is the global object, and adding x to the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have to create an instance of the function myObject before you can access its properties,

```js
/* Create an object called myObject which can be instantiated using the new keyword */
var myObject = function() {

  /* use  'this.x' to define an internal variable for x */
  this.x = 0



};

/* this is where you create a new instance of myObject which will have the    'x' property */
var myObject1 = new myObject();

var myObject2 = function() {

  return {
    increment: function() {

      myObject1.x += 1;
      console.log(myObject1.x);
    }
  }
}();

myObject2.increment();
```

**EDIT**:   Added comments to the code to explain the important modifications

Answer (score 0):

myObject1 returns an object in which x is its own property. So now you're incrementing one of the property of the object. Earlier, with `var x` you were assuming to increment property of myObject1 but in fact it was just a local variable for that function which returned your object, i.e. declaring var x in function has no effect whatsoever.

```
var myObject1 = function() {

return{
x: 0
}
}();



var myObject2 = function() {

return{
    increment: function() {
        myObject1.x +=1;
        console.log(myObject1.x);
    }
}
}();

myObject2.increment();
```

Comment: @CarlMarkham Updated.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, there is function scope, that is anything you define with var keyword is accessible within that function body.

Here you are implementing the module pattern. Your functions behave as constructors (or a factory) in your case (returning the object constructed). myObject2 cannot access x as it is defined in another scope and it is not included in the object generated by your first function.

You can return the x variable inside the return object;

```
var myObject1 = function() {
    return{
        x: 0
    }
}();
```

That makes it a property on the returned object (that is assigned to myObject1) and you can access it.

You should study "function scope" and "module pattern" in more detail.

Answer (score -1):

You're defining a variable in your functions scope. Instead, you should assign a variable to your current object (`this`) and of course return that object instead of an empty one.

```
var myObject1 = function() {
  this.x = 0;
  return this;
}();
```

Comment: For the strict mode it simply does not work, for the non-strict mode it spoils the global object.

Comment: Yes, you are returning this, which is assigned the window object when the function is immediately invoked.